# Function calling method explanation

Tags: javascript

I have some doubts about function calling. Please look at these below 3 instances.

When i need to use function calling as `function() { flip("hawaiian"); }`
When i need to use function calling as `formValid`[without braces]

Help me on this to understand better. I have still confusion on which situation i need to use these different methods.

```
hawaiiBtn.onclick = function() { flip("hawaiian"); };

formEl.onclick = formValid;

formEl.addEventListener("click", `formValid`);
```

Comment: i think first line is usually not good (to put function body to call). what if you need to execute that function multiple time? dont think 2nd and 3rd are much different, just another way to add click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Anonymous function with the inline click event

```
hawaiiBtn.onclick = function() { flip("hawaiian"); };
```

This is an anonymous function expression, that is assigned to the inline onclick event. Use this if you only need a single click handler on the element, and you don't already have an existing function, or don't want to reuse a function.

### Pass a function object to the inline click event

```
formEl.onclick = formValid;
```

Similar to the first method, but here you are passing a function object, or a named function, instead of creating a new function expression. Use this if you already have a function or want to reuse a function without duplicating code.

## element.addEventListener

The difference between this and `onclick` is this can handle multiple click handlers for the same element and same event, whereas `onclick` can only take a single function. You can use anonymous functions or function objects.

Example:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log("first fired");
});
element.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log("second fired");
});
```

Both of the above functions will execute when the click event is raised. However, doing that with the inline `onclick` will only execute the last function.

```
element.onclick = function(){
    console.log("this will never fire because it gets overwritten");
};
element.onclick = function(){
    console.log("this will fire because its the last one, and will overwrite the previous");
};
```

Comment: As an addition, keep in mind flip("hawaiian") is considered a call, and not a function reference so it needs to be wrapped in function(){} to be a valid onclick event.